# Sending Post data from 1 domain to another

Tags: php, post, get

What i m looking for is sending data from 1 domain to another using post function, i saw a person once doing it, i ve been looking for all over internet but couldn't find that solution.

Like First of all i am putting the post values in session, so they are accessible anywhere i want. And later i put these values in DB and want them to send to my other domain. So i can fetch those values over there and add to DB. It was supposed to be some sort of this,

```
$url = urlencode(http://www.domain.com/get.php='$name'.'$age'. and so on);
```

and these all values were sent to the domain above where he fetched all the values using,

```
$name1 = $name;
```

And then added to the db. I Just want help with the above url where the values are sent & how should i fetch them.

Regards,
Rocker

Comment: cURL is one way, http streams is another.

Comment: +1 for cURL.  Do you want to POST data with the request or will GET variables be ok?

Comment: See, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code for cURL examples.

Comment: http contexts, not streams: http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php

Comment: I found your cURL link interesting. I ve tried it b4. But as i am new to php, i m having trouble in fetching the data that is sent via cURL post. Can you guide me please?